# Can't Wrap Python around LAMMPS in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, lammps

I've downloaded the *8-Jan13* version of LAMMPS tar-ball from the official website and I downloaded the `Makefile.ubuntu` file from the a website/tutorial (http://katter-world.blogspot.hk/2010/05/install-lammps-on-ubuntu.html)

After executing `make ubuntu` it created the `Obj_ubuntu/` folder. I believe I've successfully been able to install it as I've been able to run commands. Even the `mpiexec -np 2 lmp_ubuntu` command.

However, I've had very little luck in wrapping Python around it. I've followed several tutorials and I've tried different combinations (after executing `make clean-all`) such as:

1. `make makeshlib`
2. `make -f Makefile.shlib ubuntu/g++/serial` (I've also executed the command without the `-f` argument, but I get the error

> make[1](http://katter-world.blogspot.hk/2010/05/install-lammps-on-ubuntu.html): *** No rule to make target `shlib'.  Stop.

I've got an error in most of the things I've tried and obviously in Python I get the following error:

> OSError: Could not load LAMMPS dynamic library

Comment: As always: what is the complete set of `make` commands you tried and what errors did each produce?